# SQL Server DELETE and SELECT Behave Differently with Same WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which is populated by a daily scheduled job that deletes the last 7 days of data and then repopulates with the 7 most recent days worth of data from another source (mainframe).

Recently, users reported a number of duplicates going back to the beginning of October 2011. ...in the magnitude of hundreds of thousand of rows.

I noticed strange behavior with the delete that runs for each job:

```
DELETE FROM fm104d 
 WHERE location = '18'
   AND (CONVERT(datetime,CASE WHEN ISDATE(pull_date)=0 THEN '19000101' 
                 ELSE pull_date END)) >  DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
```

The above returns "(0 row(s) affected)".

When I run the above after replacing the DELETE with a SELECT *, I get 32,000+ rows in return.

Why would the SELECT and DELETE behave differently?

***UPDATE***

Here is the Actual Execution Plan:

http://pastie.org/2869202

Comment: investigate this line `AND (CONVERT(datetime,CASE WHEN ISDATE(pull_date)=0 THEN '19000101' 
                 ELSE pull_date END)) >  DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
`

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: @MartinSmith Nope. No triggers.

Comment: Are you running the `DELETE` and `SELECT` under the same login? If not check that both logins have the same `dateformat` settings (default language)

Comment: Just to clarify when you write "The above returns zero rows" you mean the message reads `(0 row(s) affected)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes.  Same login. In fact, same SSMS window.

Comment: Check the query plans. It would seem to be an optimizer bug.

Comment: @ConradFrix Correct. (Thanks! Edited post for clarification)

Comment: Are you able to post the XML version of the actual execution plans?

Comment: is `[location]` a `VARCHAR` ?

Comment: Could it be default lock levels?  As in, the rows have been inserted, but not released from lock yet?  Of course, `DELETE` statements tend to crash if they run into locked rows, but could you have set something (DB2 has a `SKIP LOCKED ROWS CLAUSE`, at least).  If your `SELECT`s are running without a transaction, that _might_ explain it...

Comment: Do you have `INSTEAD OF` triggers on fm104d ?

Comment: @X-Zero - To skip rows locked by other transactions SQL Server has `READPAST` table hint [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). I don't know if this could help.

Comment: Possibilites: Triggers prevent delete  --  Permissions do not allow delete --- delete is not being 'committed' and thus is being rolled back...  referential integrity is preventing deletes from occurring on some rows.

Comment: Without execution plans I don't believe this question "can be reasonably answered in its current form." so voting to close as "not a real question"

Comment: @MartinSmith C'mon...don't be so quick to show me the door! :-)  I had to wait for my turn for the DBAs to get the execution plan (my poor developer ID didn't have the ability).  I updated post to include links to execution plan.

Comment: @MArkB - Is there any chance you could get hold of the actual execution plan rather than the estimated? This has the actual row counts coming out of each iterator and would be interesting to see where this is different as the estimated plan doesn't show any differences in estimated row counts coming out of either the CI scan or the filter.

Comment: @MartinSmith Posted link to the actual execution plan I was given just now.

Comment: @MarkB - Well that shows it is the `datetime` filter that is getting rid of all the rows but I'm baffled why it should behave differently under a `DELETE` at the moment. What version are you on?

Comment: @MartinSmith Here it is: 9.00.5057.00 - SP4 (Standard Edition (64-bit))

Comment: Same version as I've got installed on my dev machine. Can you confirm (1) What is the datatype of `PULL_DATE`? (2) Can you provide an example of one of the `PULL_DATE` values brought back by the `SELECT` for that query? (3) What is the result of `select date_format from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id=@@spid`? And I'll see if I can reproduce it here.

Comment: This seems like a contender for bounty. Anyone feeling rich?

Comment: @MartinSmith it's a VARCHAR(8) not null field and stores the date in YYYYMMDD format (i.e. 20111117).  The date_format returned is MDY

Comment: Been unable to reproduce this behavior with the same wide delete execution plan on the same version of SQL Server. Your question has a delete against `fm104d` with predicate `location = '18'` but your plan has against `fir104d` with predicate `SOURCE_LOCATION='0819'`. Are you 100% certain your `SELECT` and `DELETE` were doing the same thing?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes.  What you're seeing is my failure to 100% scrub the data before posting for the world.  Assume that '18' == '0819'.

Comment: A foreign key contraint can prevent records from beeing deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't believe this. I didn't in fact as it makes *almost* no logical sense, but in the end, the solution that worked...was to add an index.

Credit for this goes to my local DBA "Did think about adding an index? I just did to test and sure enough it works".

Here's the index as added:

```
CREATE  INDEX ixDBO_fir104d__SOURCE_LOCATION__Include
ON [dbo].[fir104d] ([SOURCE_LOCATION])
INCLUDE ([Transaction_Date],[PULL_DATE])
GO
```

I let the job run as scheduled and, sure enough, all is as it was.

My guess is that there is something in the explain plan to say it wasn't using an index / wrong index, but my developer mind can't make much sense of that level of detail.

Thanks to everybody for the time and effort you've all spent.

**UPDATE**

Received news from a different dev that the data in this table additionally corrupted to the point where it took "several hours of DBA involvement to resolve" along with the dev having to perform some other data fixes (read:data file reloads).

At the end of the day, while adding the index was probably a good thing considering the way the scheduled job runs, apparently, there was even more to the story!

Comment: You're right, I don't believe it.  The select finds the records without the index but the delete can't?  Amazing.  +50 just so I can refer to this problem later if I encounter the same thing one day.

Comment: I wonder if having a primary key would have prevented this issue in the first place?

Comment: Or maybe it was because an index was corrupted and was rebuit when added.. (we'll never really know :D)

Comment: @MatthewPK Probably! If I had to describe the system as a whole, "House of Cards" comes to mind.

Comment: @xQbert Funny thing. The way it *really* went with the DBA was he added the index, tested, removed, notified me "hey, index!", and then re-added after I formally requested. Observed problem before index was added at the end.

Comment: Still doesn't really add up. Why should the corruption not affect the `SELECT` that is scanning the same clustered index? How did the new NCI not get affected by reading corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM fm104d  where fm104d.id in 
(
select  id from fm104d 
 WHERE location = '18'
   AND (CONVERT(datetime,CASE WHEN ISDATE(pull_date)=0 THEN '19000101' 
                 ELSE pull_date END)) >  DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
)aaa
```

and give response if it deletes

p.s. : this is not the solution but will lead to decision.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite.  No ID column on this table (yes, the system is terrible). Also, performance / memory are a concern.

Comment: @MarkB. - Along the same lines as this answer you can delete from a CTE with a `SELECT` statement directly. i.e. use `;WITH CTE AS (SELECT ....) DELETE FROM CTE` but I would suggest just getting to the bottom of the original issue .

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you never want to delete when `pull_date` is not a date.
Try eliminating the explicit string replacements... perhaps there is a parsing different between the `SELECT` and `DELETE`

```
DELETE 
FROM 
    fm104d 
WHERE 
    [location] = '18' --NOTE if this is an int, then just try with 18, no dits
    AND (
         CASE ISDATE([pull_date])
         WHEN 1 THEN
             CAST([pull_date] AS DATETIME)
         ELSE
             NULL
         END  >  DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
        )
```

**EDIT:** Note that this doesn't *exactly* match your SQL because, in yours, if you time-travel back to January First, 1900 it *will* delete your row regardless.... I presumed this was not actually your intention.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation might be that there are two tables, each in a different schema.  Perhaps if you have `select` rights on both schema's but `delete` rights on only one, SQL Server might choose a different table for `delete`.

To verify this, prefix your table with the schema name (the default schema is `dbo`)

```
FROM schema1.fm104d
```

(Not tested, just a thought, no access to a SQL Server installation atm.)

Comment: Good suggestion, but in this case, sadly, there's only one -  dbo.fm104d

Answer (score 0):

For your select, add `ISDATE(pull_date)` to the select list to determine what part of the case statement these are affecting.  Look at the pull_date as well and see if there's a pattern to the format of the string common among these offenders that refuse to be deleted.

This might have some relation to the determinism of Convert and IsDate:

"ISDATE is deterministic only if you use it with the CONVERT function, if the CONVERT style parameter is specified, and style is not equal to 0, 100, 9, or 109."

See the couple of examples here where convert is nested inside isdate:

http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/181/CAST-CONVERT-nondeterministic

So try adjusting your where clause and see if that helps.  Also note that "The return value of ISDATE may be affected by LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT settings."  So maybe something on your server has changed in these regards.  Why it'd affect the delete but not the select is still strange.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this, see if you can evaluate your pull_date column first and then delete the records.

```
DELETE FROM fm104d
WHERE Location = 18 
   AND Pull_date IN
   (
      SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME,
         CASE 
            WHEN ISDATE(pull_Date) = 0
               THEN '19000101'
            ELSE pull_date
         END) AS pull_date
      FROM fm104d 
      WHERE pull_date > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
   )
```

Comment: What do you think will happen if `pull_date` is not a correct `datetime` value? While your subquery is converting this column both explicitly and safely, the outer query is doing it implicitly and... boom!